# Difficulty Accessing SharePoint Files in Docker Container for R Script Execution

Tags: docker, kubernetes, sharepoint, onedrive, rscript

I am encountering difficulties accessing SharePoint files within a Docker container for executing an R script. I have a specific R script that needs to read an Excel file stored in SharePoint, but I'm struggling to configure the Docker container properly to enable this access.

Background:
I am working on a project where we have an R script (script.R) that performs data analysis tasks.
The script requires reading an Excel file (Project-Management-Sample-Data.xlsx) stored in SharePoint.
We are using Docker to containerize our application for deployment and reproducibility purposes.

I am seeking guidance on how to properly configure the Docker container to access SharePoint files for executing the R script. Specifically, I would appreciate any insights or solutions on:
How to correctly set up the Dockerfile to ensure access to SharePoint files.
Any additional configurations or settings needed within the R script or Docker environment to facilitate file access.
Best practices or alternative methods for accessing SharePoint files within a Docker container.